# How do i redirect a url/abc to url/abc/live-preview where abc is a variable name?

Tags: nginx, redirect, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location, nginx-config

I have a url - https://sambit.com/hub/abc which i want to redirect to  https://sambit.com/admin/sites/editors/hub-page/abc/live-preview where abc is a variable value .
i wrote a nginx config like this -
`location /hub { rewrite ^/hub(.*)$ https://iwillonlytestit.replica.bangthetable.in/admin/sites/editors/hub-page/$1/live-preview permanent; }`
but it doesn't seems to redirect to the url i want .
its redirecting to https://sambit.com/admin/sites/editors/hub-page/.*/live-preview.
Can someone please help me out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to achieve the task like follows -

```
rewrite ^(/hub)(.*)$   https://iwillonlytestit.replica.bangthetable.in/admin/sites/editors/hub-page$2/live-preview permanent;
```

this redirects from   https://iwillonlytestit.replica.bangthetable.in/hub/abc  to  https://iwillonlytestit.replica.bangthetable.in/admin/sites/editors/hub-page/abc/live-preview